# Deploying Blazor server-side app to Azure using VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, vscode-extensions, blazor-server-side

The question is the title really. How do I deploy a Blazor server-side app to Azure from within VS Code?

I'm using .NET Core 3.0 preview 9.

I've installed the templates with `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview9.19424.4`

I'm trying to deploy a project created by by issuing `dotnet new blazorserver -o WebApplication1`

I'm trying to do the deployment using the Azure App Service (ms-azuretools.vscode-azureappservice) extension.

The deployment appears to succeed and I can see the files in Azure using Kudu.

In the Azure settings for the App Service, there are no application settings of note. I'm on a free plan, it's set to 32-bit, HTTP2, Websockets on.

There is a single virtual (application) path configured for / pointing to site\wwwroot.

When I navigate to the site I get a 403.

UPDATE:

Now that I've discovered I need to do a `dotnet publish` followed by a deploy, I now get a 500 error: "HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure"

Comment: The problem has gone already. Due to updates in framework or templates I think.
But thank you very much for algorithm in your question!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this eventually.

Since the .NET Core version was pre-release, I had to make sure it was installed on Azure by adding it as an extension. I followed the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#deploy-aspnet-core-preview-release-to-azure-app-service

I then found the following documentation (which was for a previous version but the documentation for the preview version didn't include these instructions): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-2.2 - the fix was basically to add the following to the project file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

After that, it started working.